# Определение размерности признаков для нейросети

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Задача из датасета MNIST

Работа с признаками:

```
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28*28).astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28*28).astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)
```

Полносвязная сеть работает нормально:

```py
num_classes = 10
model1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

А вот при валидации сверточной сети возникают проблемы:

```py
model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model2.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model2.load_weights('conv_net.h5')

x_t = x_test.reshape(28, 28, 10000)
model2.evaluate(x_t, y_test)
```

При попытке применения evaluate возникает ошибка: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28, 10000). Я не могу понять, как необходимо изменить x_test.reshape(), чтобы можно было применить нейросеть (model2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1).astype('float32')
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=-1).astype('float32')

x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)


model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
#model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(28,28,1), activation='relu'))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model2.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model2.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

**output:**

```
Epoch 1/5
48000/48000 [==============================] - 68s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.1476 - acc: 0.9528 - val_loss: 0.0569 - val_acc: 0.9836
Epoch 2/5
48000/48000 [==============================] - 71s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.0492 - acc: 0.9845 - val_loss: 0.0446 - val_acc: 0.9868
Epoch 3/5
48000/48000 [==============================] - 73s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.0339 - acc: 0.9894 - val_loss: 0.0451 - val_acc: 0.9876
Epoch 4/5
48000/48000 [==============================] - 77s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.0258 - acc: 0.9923 - val_loss: 0.0428 - val_acc: 0.9877
Epoch 5/5
48000/48000 [==============================] - 75s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.0202 - acc: 0.9935 - val_loss: 0.0398 - val_acc: 0.9892
Out[306]: <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x1be026801d0>
```

**проверка точности модели на тестовой выборке:**

```
In [307]: model2.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
10000/10000 [==============================] - 4s 450us/sample - loss: 0.0344 - acc: 0.9897
Out[307]: [0.03438742905126128, 0.9897]
```

Comment: При этом выдает 

ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 28, 28]